Unable to disable the readonly kubelet port in GKE
I've tried to follow this guide in accordance with the email that we have received about the unsecure readonly port exposed by kubelet.
The script I used is pasted below:
#!/bin/bash

echo Please enter the Google Cloud Project Id:
read PROJECT_ID
echo "Working with Project '$PROJECT_ID' ..."

PROJECT_NAME=$(gcloud projects describe $PROJECT_ID --format="value(name)")
echo "Project Name is '$PROJECT_NAME'. If it's okay, type OK"
read PROJECT_CONFIRMATION

if [ "OK" = "$PROJECT_CONFIRMATION" ]; then
    echo "Proceeding with project '$PROJECT_NAME'."
else
    echo "Exiting.."
    exit 0
fi

DEBUG_POD_NAME="debug-curl-pod"
NAMESPACE="default"

# List all the clusters in the project
CLUSTERS_LIST=$(gcloud --project=$PROJECT_ID container clusters list --format="value(name, location)")

echo "$CLUSTERS_LIST" | while IFS= read -r CLUSTER_LINE; do
    read -r CLUSTER_NAME CLUSTER_LOCATION <<< "$CLUSTER_LINE"
    echo "Processing cluster '$CLUSTER_NAME' in location '$CLUSTER_LOCATION'"

    echo "Setting context for cluster: $CLUSTER_NAME in location: $CLUSTER_LOCATION..."
    gcloud container clusters get-credentials "$CLUSTER_NAME" --zone="$CLUSTER_LOCATION" --project="$PROJECT_ID"    
    
    # For each cluster, update the flag, and ensure that it was updated. This will only affect resources that get created in the future.
    gcloud --project=$PROJECT_ID container clusters update $CLUSTER_NAME --location=$CLUSTER_LOCATION --no-enable-insecure-kubelet-readonly-port
    CLUSTER_CONFIG_OUTPUT=$(gcloud --project=$PROJECT_ID container clusters describe $CLUSTER_NAME --location=$CLUSTER_LOCATION --flatten=nodePoolDefaults.nodeConfigDefaults --format="value(nodeKubeletConfig)")
    echo "Cluster '$CLUSTER_NAME' config output: '$CLUSTER_CONFIG_OUTPUT'"    
    
    # Update all the NODE_POOLS within the cluster, with the same config. This will only affect resources that get created in the future.
    NODE_POOLS=$(gcloud --project=$PROJECT_ID container node-pools list --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --location=$CLUSTER_LOCATION --format="value(name)")
    

    # Create a new curl pod to query the nodes
    kubectl -n $NAMESPACE run $DEBUG_POD_NAME --image=curlimages/curl --restart=Never --command -- sleep 3600

    # Wait for the curl pod to be ready
    kubectl -n $NAMESPACE wait --for=condition=ready pod/$DEBUG_POD_NAME 

    echo "$NODE_POOLS" | while IFS= read -r nodepoolline; do
        echo "Working with nodepool $nodepoolline"
        gcloud --project=$PROJECT_ID container node-pools update $nodepoolline --cluster=$CLUSTER_NAME --location=$CLUSTER_LOCATION --no-enable-insecure-kubelet-readonly-port
        NODE_POOL_CONFIG_OUTPUT=$(gcloud --project=$PROJECT_ID container node-pools describe $nodepoolline --cluster=$CLUSTER_NAME --location=$CLUSTER_LOCATION --flatten=config --format="value(kubeletConfig)")
        echo "Cluster '$CLUSTER_NAME' Nodepool '$nodepoolline' config output: '$NODE_POOL_CONFIG_OUTPUT'"

        # recycle all the nodes present in the cluster

        NODE_DETAILS=$(kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns='NAME:.metadata.name,IP:.status.addresses[?(@.type=="InternalIP")].address,ZONE:.metadata.labels.failure-domain\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/zone' | tail +2)

        echo "$NODE_DETAILS" | while IFS= read -r NODE_LINE; do
            read -r NODE_NAME NODE_IP NODE_ZONE <<< "$NODE_LINE"
            URL_TO_TEST="http://$NODE_IP:10255/metrics"

            OUTPUT=$(kubectl exec -n $NAMESPACE $DEBUG_POD_NAME -- curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" $URL_TO_TEST)

            # Display the output
            echo "HTTP response status for curl command for URL '$URL_TO_TEST' on node $NODE_IP: $OUTPUT"

            # kubectl drain $NODE_NAME --ignore-daemonsets --delete-local-data
            # gcloud compute instances delete $NODE_NAME --zone $NODE_ZONE --quiet
        done # NODE_LINE while loop end
    done # nodepool while loop end
    # Delete the pod
    kubectl -n $NAMESPACE delete pod $DEBUG_POD_NAME
    echo "Done executing script!"
done # cluster while loop end

I've tried to recycle the nodes as well, but the kubelet service gets created again with the 10255 reachable. What am I missing here?

Refer to this document and also check this community issue which might be helpful for you.

I see, thanks @PranayKumarKyasala!
